# Rendering animation problem

Tags: rendering, animation

[image]my animation is not rendering. it just goes to a black screen like this:[image]

Comment: actually, it renders the first frame then says "Permission Denied Cannot save file"

Comment: Please instead of asking the same question ( http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67418/blend-file-not-rendering-properly) please add more information on the original post to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you may have a bad path in the Output directory. From your screenshot, it looks like 'Science'. Replace that with an actual path to an existing directory for which you have read/write permissions.

If you click the little folder icon at the far right of that field, you can browse to your desired render directory.

Ensure that the path you enter in that field ends with a trailing slash (or backslash if on Windows)

Comment: I was in the desktop category with no specific file assigned and I hit the accept button and it just put in 2 slashes. Can I render it like that?

Comment: Probably, but it sounds like your renders would then all end up in the root of your file system. Try creating a folder called 'renders' somewhere on your disk that is easy to find. Then use the blender Output browse button to browse to that folder and select it.